# Recaptcha in eccube4

Tags: recaptcha

so my recaptchautil.php looks like this

```
<?php

namespace Eccube\Customize\Util;

class RecaptchaUtil {
    private static $secret = '6Lc1_AUoAAAAAOayHg1RvrCHGxl-csYy6JA49Ds_';
    private static $contentStr = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%s&response=%s&';
    public const SITE_KEY = '6Lc1_AUoAAAAAJvU7hcU-x-d5DrDgqPn0eIDieU7';
    public const INPUT_NAME = 'recaptchaResponse';
    private const MIN_SCORE = 0.5;

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function check($response){
        $url = sprintf(self::$contentStr, self::$secret, $response);
        
        $recaptcha = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        $result = $recaptcha->success && ( property_exists($recaptcha, 'score') && $recaptcha->score >= self::MIN_SCORE );
    
        return (bool)$result;
      }
}
```

my recaptcha.twig looks like this

```
{% set site_key = constant('Customize\\Util\\RecaptchaUtil::SITE_KEY') %}
{% set inputName = constant('Customize\\Util\\RecaptchaUtil::INPUT_NAME') %}

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{ site_key }}"></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        var shape = $('{{ shape }}');
        var recaptchaInput = $("<input>").attr({type: 'hidden', name: '{{ inputName }}'});

        form.append(recaptchaInput);

        form.on('submit', function(e){
            grecaptcha.execute('{{ site_key }}', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
                recaptchaInput.val(token);
                form[0].submit();
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

when i checked the recaptcha parameter value, the following error was shown
object(stdClass)#2899 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "invalid-input-response" } }

i followed the same steps as https://enginiya.com/entry/recaptcha-introduce
it would be glad if someone could help
thank you